# React Native app crashing when launched on my ios device

Tags: react-native

I have created a mobile React Native Typescript app for Android and iOS. The app works on the Android studio emulator (`Pixel 5 API 31`) and the Xcode emulator (`iPhone 14 Pro Max - iOS 16.4`). Whenever I launch the app on my iPhone, it stays on my custom-created splash screen for around 15 - 20 seconds and then it crashes. When I install the app on my phone, it successfully launches but after I close the app, it always crashes on the splash screen. I'm still developing the app and some time ago, it never crashed and now I cannot figure out what change I have done that is crashing it. I started noticing this crashing after removing the default React Native splash screen and creating the custom splash screen. I have rolled back most of my package's version but still no luck. I did get a warning-like error recently which I have attached. I need help with this as I don't know how to proceed. Or at most can I get info on how I can see the logs of it crashing? Let me know if more details are required.

Some sources say I need to also install `react-native-reanimated@2.12.0`, but I'm never able to build the Android app, it always fails.

I am using `VMware Workstation 16` - `macOS Ventura Version 13.0 Beta`. `Xcode - Version 14.3`.

My device is the `iPhone 8 Plus` - `iOS version 16.5.1`.

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.1",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.11",
        "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.7",
        "@react-navigation/elements": "1.3.17",
        "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.12",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.16",
        "axios": "1.4.0",
        "moment": "2.29.4",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.8",
        "react-native-animated-pagination-dot": "0.4.0",
        "react-native-dotenv": "3.4.8",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
        "react-native-keychain": "8.1.1",
        "react-native-restart": "0.0.27",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.3",
        "react-native-screens": "3.20.0",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
        "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
        "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0",
        "react-native-url-polyfill": "1.3.0",
        "react-native-webview": "12.0.2",
        "react-native-youtube-iframe": "2.2.2",
        "react-navigation-stack": "2.10.4",
        "react-navigation-tabs": "2.11.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.22.1",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.22.3",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "3.2.0",
        "@tsconfig/react-native": "3.0.2",
        "@types/jest": "29.5.2",
        "@types/node": "20.2.5",
        "@types/react": "18.2.8",
        "@types/react-native": "0.71.8",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.8",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.8",
        "babel-jest": "29.5.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "5.0.0",
        "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "4.1.0",
        "eslint": "8.42.0",
        "jest": "29.5.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.4",
        "react-native-svg-transformer": "1.0.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "5.1.3"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "node"
        ]
    }
}
```

warning-like error:

```bash
success Successfully built the app
2023-06-27 22:19:21.388 xcodebuild[1446:10178] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCo reDevice=disabled)
2023-06-27 22:19:22.497 xcodebuild[1446:10243] DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-21677/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:382
Details: (null) deviceType from 5d1e807a96f069db613b63e4ca211ed2610bbe8c was NULL when -platform called.
Object: <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f7d55bcf630>
Method: -platform
Thread: <NSThread: 0x6000006d4400>{number = 3, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2023-06-27 22:19:23.004 xcodebuild[1446:10309] DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRo ot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-21677/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:382
Details: (null) deviceType from 5d1e807a96f069db613b63e4ca211ed2610bbe8c was NULL when -platform called.
Object: <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f7d55bcf630>
Method: -platform
Thread: <NSThread: 0x600000990040>(number = 8, name = (null))
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2023-06-27 22:19:23.302 xcodebuild[1446:10309] DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRo at/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-21677/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRcmoteDeviceData.m:382
Details: (null) deviceType from 6d1e807a96f069db613b63e4ca211ed2610bbe8c was NULL when -platform called.
Object: <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f7d65bcf630>
Method: -platform Thread: <NSThread: 0x600000990040>{number = 8, name = (null))
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide. 2023-06-27 22:19:27.663 xcodebuild[1446:10333] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition info
Installing and launching your app on Amandeep iPhone
success Installed the app on the device.
```

Comment: have you tried building in Xcode?  You will get better crash logs. Also can you please add the warning as text instead of as an image?

Comment: How do I do that? Do I just click the Run logo in Xcode? I will give it a try. Ahhh, I will edit the question if it comes up next time.